# Why am I suddenly seeing FileVault errors on my Windows 7 box?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Windows 7 machine, with no VMs and no OSX anywhere in sight.  Yesterday, after not having done anything unusual (such as installing new software) recently, I started getting errors <s>at random times</s> when I plug in or unplug peripherals, such as USB devices or speakers, grouped in the Taskbar with Windows Explorer windows.  They look like this:

```
---------------------------
FileVault
---------------------------
An internal error occurred (object: clsid-not-found(Object::Remote::CLIENT|
(Object::Remote::PROTOCOL_LOCAL|FV::FvServerApp::00000001)
CID_SafeArchive::FileArchiveCache)).
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

A bit of Googling tells me that FileVault is the name of an OSX system component that encrypts drives, but that's all I've got.

- Trying to search for results specific to this problem haven't turned up anything useful.
- Checking Task Manager for anything named FileVault among running processes turns up nothing.
- Loading up a program I wrote under a debugger and opening a File Open dialog, which causes shell extensions to be loaded into the process, and then checking the list of loaded DLLs for anything with a name like "FileVault" turns up nothing.
- Looking for FileVault under the Programs and Features control panel turns up nothing.
- The first thing I'd suspect is that I've somehow picked up a virus, but a Full scan by Windows Defender turns up nothing.

So I'm about at my wit's end here.  Does anyone have any idea what's going on on my system, and how I can make it stop?

Comment: I've just updated some drivers (with one freemium app) and the same error pops up, win 8 x64 ent (DOMAIN). Time frame proposes that it's a driver error or fringerprint-subsystem bug (apps,drivers,apis).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, it's a driver + registry config error.

http://forums.cnet.com/7723-12546_102-251765/fingerprint-error-clsid-not-found-on-starting-windows-vist/

Reinstall the driver, the deep way if needed, showing hidden devices in device manager, selecting show by CONNECTION (view) and deleting the whole chain inherited and superseded by finger-touch sensor.